# Dockerfile - Error: Cannot find module 'react'

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a React app that I'm trying to Dockerize. Here is my Dockerfile and docker-compose:

```
FROM node:16.13.1
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN mkdir -p node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-93
RUN curl -L https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v7.0.1/linux-x64-93_binding.node -o node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-93/binding.node

RUN npm install -g npm@9.1.2
RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.0 -g
RUN npm rebuild node-sass

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD \["npm", "start"\]
```

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web-cnss:
    build: './editor'
    ports: [ "3000:3000" ]
    container_name: WEB-CNSS
    volumes:
      - '/app/node_modules'
```

Somehow I need to specify the npm version and also install react-scripts, otherwise it gives an error in another computer.
Besides this, in my computer everything works well, however, my objective is that anyone can clone my project and build it by just simply running "docker-compose up".

I tested it on my colleague's computer, and this was the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react'
WEB-CNSS     | Require stack:
WEB-CNSS     | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
WEB-CNSS     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
WEB-CNSS     |     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
WEB-CNSS     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:43:31)
WEB-CNSS     |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
WEB-CNSS     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
WEB-CNSS     |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
WEB-CNSS     |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
WEB-CNSS     |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
WEB-CNSS     |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
WEB-CNSS     |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
WEB-CNSS     |   requireStack: [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js' ]
WEB-CNSS     | }
```

Maybe it is my package.json that has some errors, so here it is as well:

```
{
   "name": "editor",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
      "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.3",
      "@convergence/convergence": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
      "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
      "ace-builds": "^1.4.14",
      "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
      "dropzone": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
      "easymde": "^2.16.0",
      "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
      "react": "^18.0.0",
      "react-ace": "^9.5.0",
      "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.3",
      "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
      "react-drag-drop-files": "^2.3.7",
      "react-dropzone": "^14.2.2",
      "react-pro-sidebar": "^0.7.1",
      "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
      "react-simplemde-editor": "^5.0.2",
      "react-sticky-box": "^1.0.2",
      "simplemde": "^1.11.2",
      "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "predeploy": "npm run build",
      "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
   "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
         "react-app",
         "react-app/jest"
      ]
   },
   "browserslist": {
      "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
      ]
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@convergencelabs/ace-collab-ext": "^0.6.0",
      "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
   }
}
```

I also tested the answers on another similar questions posted here on StackOverflow, but they didn't work.

Comment: I think that the problem lays with the node version installed. Have you checked that?

Comment: are you sure that copy package-lock into dockerfile is right?. I think you just should copy package.json and then npm install to build that file then.

Comment: @Alen.Toma The version I use in the dockerfile is the same that I have installed on my local computer. My colleague doesn't even have node installed. But, since this is a docker container, the FROM node:16.13.1 should install the node on the container, no?

Comment: I also tried without package-lock, but the error persisted. @aliFalahati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your Dockerfile `COPY`s in the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files, you never actually `RUN npm install` or a similar command.  A Dockerfile often uses [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci) for better reproducibility.  Put this right after you `COPY` in the package metadata.

```bash
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
```

Why does it work on your system?  Two ideas come to mind, and both point at things to verify in your setup.

You should make sure that you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the host's library tree, at least contains the line

```
node_modules
```

If you don't have this, then the later `COPY ./ ./` line will copy the host's `node_modules` directory over what `npm ci` installs.  In your original form without the `npm ci`, it's probable this was the only thing providing a `node_modules` directory, but it depended on having run `npm` commands on the host first.

The second possibility is the anonymous volume for the `node_modules` directory.  In your `docker-compose.yml` file you should delete the `modules:` block

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web-cnss:
    build: './editor'
    ports: [ "3000:3000" ]
    # container_name: WEB-CNSS  # unnecessary
    # volumes:                  # unnecessary and potentially problematic
    #   - '/app/node_modules'
```

The anonymous volume sticks around even if a container is deleted and recreated, and its content hides the content in the image.  If you ever used a debugging command like `docker-compose exec web-cnss npm install`, the results of that would stick around in the anonymous volume, but that wouldn't be part of your image and you wouldn't see its effects on a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this pattern to check that you get this error or not again

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.0 -g --silent
RUN npm rebuild node-sass

COPY . ./

Expose 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: If i do not specify the version 9.1.2 it gives an error. That is why i specified it on my dockerfile:
`
#0 3.280 npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.3 -> 9.1.2
#0 3.280 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.1.2
#0 3.281 npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.1.2 to update!
`

Comment: npm install -g npm is for updating npm. and you dont need it at all. when you use an image with its version (here node:16.13.1) then you have the latest version of component inside it. and its not necessary here. you should remove this command in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but why does it gives an error then? It forces me to run npm install -g npm@9.1.2 ...

Answer (score 0):

please remove the command line in dockerfile as follows:

```
...

# RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.0  -g --silent
...
```

hope this help you.

Comment: I'm already doing that on my dockerfile.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Sorry but no, it gives this error:

`
#0 2.959 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
#0 2.962 npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
#0 2.962 npm ERR!
#0 2.962 npm ERR! While resolving: editor@0.1.0
#0 2.963 npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
#0 2.963 npm ERR! node_modules/react
#0 2.963 npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
`

Comment: Can you show me entire error messages?

Comment: If I remove completely the line you mentioned it simply says: "sh: 1: react-scripts: not found"